# How to show ul when clicking on link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with this simple jQuery code.

My HTML:

```
<ul class="menu-affix nav-hover">
    <li id="toggle-area"><a>Areas</a></li>
    <li id="toggle-industry"><a>Indrustry</a></li>
</ul>
```

when click on li area, there is another element in the same page that I want to add a class "open": There is it:

```
<li id="show-area" class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon ic-casa ic-bar"></i>Áreas de Atuação</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="title-dropdown">CNI</li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1208)">Competitividade</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(770)">Desenvolvimento Associativo</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1250)">Economia</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1251)">Infraestrutura</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1252)">Inovação</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1253)">Internacionalização</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1254)">Leis e Normas</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1255)">Meio Ambiente</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1256)">Pequenas Empresas</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1257)">Política Industrial</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(426)">Propriedade Intelectual</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1259)">Trabalho</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1260)">Tributação</a></li>
          <li class="title-dropdown">SISTEMA INDÚSTRIA</li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1261)">Educação e Tecnologia</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1262)">Qualidade de Vida</a></li>
          <li><a tal:attributes="href python:urlById(1263)">Responsibilidade Social</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

and my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle-area').click(function(){
    if (! $('#show-area').hasClass('open')){
      $('#show-area').addClass('open');
    }
    else {
      $('#show-area').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

This is not working, what I am missing? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though code inside click event handler can be one line `$('#show-area').toggleClass('open');`, it works "as is": [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynqmtht/). Maybe you have multiple elements with same ID? And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynqmtht/1/) with `.toggleClass()`

Comment: Well for starters you could replace the whole `if/else` thing by `$('#show-area').toggleClass('open');`

Comment: I already have checked it! Just one id. =/

Comment: Look at your console, there may be some errors.

Comment: My console is not showing any error, and the jQuery still working for another things in this page.

Comment: You should make your code more universal, for example `<li id="toggle-area"><a>Areas</a></li>` may become `<li data-toggle="#show-area">Areas</li>`, than `$('[data-toggle]').click(function(){$( $(this).data('toggle') ).toggleClass('open')})`

Comment: Try to debug more, add some console output on click event, check what happens there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle-area').click(function(){
    $('#show-area').toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

This will remove the class if it's there or add it if it's not.

Comment: Yes, this works fine in all cases, except mine. I just don't know why this is not working.. =[

Comment: @daniel_serretti you should provide example in which it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jacques I still don't know whether replacing correct code with another correct one (yes, it's much shorter, as I also mentioned in comments) is useful or not.

Comment: I discovered the error.. I'm using bootstrap too, and when i click out of the ul that I want to toggle, this open and close immediately with my click, here is my solution: $('#toggle-area').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#show-area a.dropdown-toggle').focus().click()},
          100)
      });

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class doesn't mean it will show/hide the element.

## CSS

You will need CSS to achieve this:

```
#show-area {
   display:none;
}

#show-area.open {
   display: block; 
}
```

The above is a very simple way that could make the show/hide happen.
It's saying that on default the element with the ID show-area is hidden (display: none)

Then it says that when the element with the ID show-area has a class 'open' it is shown (display: block)

[Refer to this website for help](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

## jQuery

Another way to achieve what you want is to use jQuery to show and hide the element

```
if (! $('#show-area').hasClass('open')){
   $('#show-area').show();
}
else {
   $('#show-area').hide();
}
```

This will either need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#show-area').hide();
});
```

OR

In your css:

```
#show-area {
   display:none;
}
```